# We need to migrate SVN to a new server but need to keep original hostname in URL

Tags: svn, proxy

The original server is hosting several services besides subversion, and we cannot just change the hostname. But many existing build scripts would have to change if we use the new host name in the URL. Is there some way we could use a network proxy or something that would redirect any svn:// traffic directed at the original host to the new host?

Comment: Probably best if moved to ServerFault.

Answer (score 4):

If you're only interested in the Subversion port 3690, then a simple TCP proxy application such as [datapipe](http://jeff.bovine.net/Datapipe) would do the trick.

If you're willing to change the server name (once), then I would recommend changing it to a logical name such as `subversion` or something, so your URLs read `svn://subversion/repo/...`. Then changing the location of the server is just changing one logical host address.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be possible to run some script to change all other scripts.